# Does this sequence diverge to ∞?

Tags: infinity, divergent-series, sequences-and-series

The sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is defined as follows:

$$a_n:= \begin{cases} 0 \quad \text{if} \quad n \quad \text{is odd}\\ n \quad \text{if} \quad n \quad \text{is even}\end{cases} \quad .$$

Does $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ diverge to $+\infty \quad ?$

Comment: The values of $a_n$ get arbitrarily large as $n$ grows, what does that tell you about the convergence/divergence of the sequence?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? Check the definition of convergence to $+ \infty$. And to add to the comment of Allesandro: Not all values become arbitrarily large, infinitely many of them are zero.

Comment: Since half the values do not follow the definition of convergence to infinity, then this sequence is not divergent to infinity? It is still divergent, but just not to a single value correct?

Comment: @Alessandro "The values of an get arbitrarily large as n grows" No they do not.

Answer (score 3):

no, because a sequence is divergent to $+\infty$ if and only if (by definition):
$$
\forall M\in\mathbb{R^+}:\exists\nu\in\mathbb{N}\ \ |\ \  n\gt\nu \implies a_n > M
$$
which is obviously false since when n is odd: 
$$
\forall M\in\mathbb{R^+},n\in\mathbb{N},n \mbox{ odd}:\ \ \ a_n < M \ \ \ \ \ (\mbox{because } a_n=0)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is actually oscillating sequence. You can't say this sequence diverge to ∞. Because of the definition of divergence to infinity. But it has a divergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $a_n$ diverges to infinity if and only if every subsequence of $a_n$ is unbounded above.

Using this  information, you tell me: is the even subsequence $a_{2k}$ unbounded above? What about the odd subsequence, $a_{2k+1}$? What can you conclude from this?